# Incompatible dimensions [scilab] or [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, dimensions, dimension, scilab, incompatibletypeerror

i want to test this program with scilab, but when i run it, i get this error :

**ATTENTION: Transposition of the line X vector to obtain compatible dimensions
plot2d: Wrong dimension of input arguments: Incompatible dimensions.**

here is the program :

```
t=0:400;
if t>=0 & t<=20 then
   v=0
else 
   v=15
end
plot(t,v)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are attempting to create a vector `v` whose values depend on the values of `t`. This means that where `t` is between `0` and `20`, then `v` must be equal to `0`, otherwise it must be equal to `15`.

This code should produce what you are looking for:

```
t = 0:400;

v = zeros(size(t));
v(t > 20) = 15;

plot(t,v);
```

Actually, you have to create a zero-filled vector `v` of the same size of `t` and then, using a logical indexing, you have to set the values of `v` to `15` in correspondance of `t` being greater than `20`.

Comment: thanks for your help, but can you help me to make the program of this graph please, [link](http://www.amperiste.fr/sitezz/default/files/cycle_extraurbain.JPG)

Comment: It's not a program, it's a plot. Either find the equation or retrieve its data.

Comment: that's the problem, with the equation it's impossible to know, but there is a possibility with the data. I have the data but I need to make a loop for or if, because i don't want to repeat each time v (t <) or v (t>) :(